# C# List.Foreach of Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, list, foreach, anonymous-types

If I have the following anonymous type List defined:

```
var list = new[] {
    new { guid = "f501fbb2-c724-49ef-b7d5-954d7e9329a3", url = "~/Home" },
    new { guid = "37df9c3e-f816-4ef9-9023-5f26295feffa", url = "~/Contact" }
}.ToList();
```

How do I perform a List.ForEach(delegate) on the list?  I keep getting a AnonymousType issue:
*"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'anonymous method' to 'System.Action.'"*

(Code tried)

```
list.ForEach(
    delegate(var item) { 
        // Some function here
    }
);
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use `.ForEach` rather than a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Style preference, .ForEach seems to be a lot cleaner to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using a lambda expression instead.

```
list.ForEach(item => /* magic */);
```

Comment: Thank you, my oversight, using delegate instead of lambda